# Why is 'a b' OK in C++?

Tags: c++, char

Looking at the following code:

```
string str = "xxxaa  bbcc";

int pos1 = str.find("a  b"); // pos1=4
int pos2 = str.find('a  b'); // pos2=7
int pos3 = str.find('a  bb'); // error C2015: too many characters in constant
```

- Why doesn't the second `'a  b'` trigger any errors? It always seems to me that `''` can only hold one char, but OK for 4 ones here? And why will I get `pos2=7` (just like only the last one char `'b'` is passed in)?
- From the second one, it seems `''` can hold for multiple chars, why won't it be ok for more than 5 chars, see the third example?

Comment: In a nutshell: multicharacter literals are implementation defined.